# Determining loop invariant for a recursive function

Tags: loops, recursion, loop-invariant

Assume you have a function that returns the difference in length between two arrays, however, it's not using the conventional methods to find length but rather a recursive function.
Can you help me find a loop invariant? I understand the loop invariant is something that must be true before the condition and after the condition. However, I am not really able to understand it. Here's the code:

```
function func (int arr1_length, int arr2_length) {
   if (arr1_length == 0 && arr2_length == 0) return 0;
   if (arr1_length == 0) return arr2_length;
   if (arr2_length == 0) return arr1_length;
   return func (arr1_length-1, arr2_length-1);
}
```

The first call is func(arr1.length, arr2.length);

Comment: Small correction: this function is using recursion, not a while loop.

Comment: You're correct, let me update it

Comment: both arguments should be >0

Comment: Deleted my old comment cause I misspoke; both arguments must be > -1, since a starting value of 0 is perfectly fine.